# Samsung Galaxy S2 shuts off when plugged in: screen goes black then a grey empty battery appears

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, battery, charging, shutdown

Samsung Galaxy S2 shuts off when plugged in. The screen goes black then a grey empty battery appears for a second then disappears. This "flashes" several times in about 4-5 second intervals. I can not turn the phone on unless the phone is unplugged.

If I try to holding the power button for around a minute it then goes to the "charging screen" (the battery with the charging level in green). This happens even if the phone is partially charged. If my phone is on and I plug it in it stays on for almost a minute then the screen goes black, grey battery appears blinks for about 3-5 minutes same as I mentioned above. When the phone is fully charged, when I get it to that state, it does stay charged.

I have taken out the battery, I have tried a different charger. I am convinced this is a hardware problem. Also this started happening about 3 days ago. Any ideas as to what may be wrong are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this approach](http://www.askmefast.com/Why_wont_my_samsung_galaxy_note_charge_i_have_tried_numerous_chargers_and_it_still_wont_charge-qna4057479.html#q2672974) and it worked for me (and looks like for other people too):

> The way I got mine working was, remove the battery, plug the charger in, wait 5 seconds then start touching the battery on and off of the contacts on the phone, did this quite quickly, then the phone will vibrate. As soon as it starts vibrating, push the battery into the phone so it's permanently on. I got a picture saying the battery with nearly fully charged. Then when the picture goes off, the red LED came on to say it was charging. I left it like that for an hour, then turned it on and it's been working since.

Answer (score 0):

It is the issue with the micro USB on the phone. Best you get it checked at a authorized service center.

For a temporary fix:
Take a sharp pin and put it under the micro USB port and twist the USB port towards the screen. That should be a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Clean lint out of usb port with a safety pin, be careful with connector inside...lint from pocket is issue

Comment: Why would you assume lint is the cause of the problem???

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe using a non-supported charger? I know they can produce wrong internal voltages which can corrupt the functionality of hardware. If I try to charge my z3c with my iPhone charger I'm unable to use the screen anymore since it won't recognize any input. And very sensible Hardware like the CPU will instantly shut down when noticing wrong voltages. Maybe that's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with your battery. The same thing occurred in my Panasonic P66 phone too. It usually occurs when you're running an application which drains the battery more(ex: Games, Camera) while the phone is plugged. And when the battery percentage is about 15%-25%. You can overcome this issue by replacing your battery.

Yesterday I bought another charging cable. and now the phone charges as usual. So try replacing the charging cable before replacing the battery because, cost for a battery is higher than that for a cable.